# How to set custom seed for pseudo-random number generator

Tags: matlab, random

I need to perform few tests where I use `randn` pseudo random number generator. How can I set the seed on my own, so every time I run this test I will get the same results? (yeah, I know it's a little bit weird, but that's the problem).

I've found the `RANDSTREAM` object that has the `seed` property, but it's read only. Is there any way to use it for seeding the generator?

Comment: No, that's not weird. It's actually fairly important for testing and debugging.

Comment: @Jonas, yup, especially when it comes to repeatability of the results...

Comment: Note that to do the opposite, i.e. to avoid repeatability every time we restart Matlab, the command is [`rng('shuffle')`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html), which sets the seed based on the current time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The old way of doing it:

```
randn('seed',0)
```

The new way:

```
s = RandStream('mcg16807','Seed',0)
RandStream.setDefaultStream(s)
```

Note that if you use the new way, `rand` and `randn` share the same stream so if you are calling both, you may find different numbers being generated compared to the old method (which has separate generators). The old method is still supported for this reason (and legacy code).

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsn94u0-1.html for more info.

Comment: Note that the link now shows the 2011a version which uses the `rng` function.

Comment: Also, it looks like they now recommend using `RandStream.setGlobalStream` instead of `RandStream.setDefaultStream`.  Apparently it will replace that function in future versions.

Comment: @Gacek May you help me...I follow the instructions but I didn't get the same values

Comment: @Mazzy, honestly, I don't know what could be wrong without seeing your results and/or code...

Comment: but are there no way to set the seed and do the random generation in the same call, do I need to create an own function with just 2 lines then?

Answer (score 10):

You can just call `rng(mySeed)` to set the seed for the global stream (tested in Matlab R2011b).  This affects the `rand`, `randn`, and `randi` functions.

The [same page that James linked to](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsn94u0-1.html#bsu1ysw) lists this as the recommended alternative to various old methods (see the middle cell of the right column of the table).

Here's some example code:

```
format long;             % Display numbers with full precision
format compact;          % Get rid of blank lines between output
mySeed = 10;
rng(mySeed);             % Set the seed
disp(rand([1,3]));
disp(randi(10,[1,10]));
disp(randn([1,3]));
disp(' ');
rng(mySeed);             % Set the seed again to duplicate the results
disp(rand([1,3]));
disp(randi(10,[1,10]));
disp(randn([1,3]));
```

Its output is:

```
   0.771320643266746   0.020751949359402   0.633648234926275
     8     5     3     2     8     2     1     7    10     1
   0.060379730526407   0.622213879877005   0.109700311365407

   0.771320643266746   0.020751949359402   0.633648234926275
     8     5     3     2     8     2     1     7    10     1
   0.060379730526407   0.622213879877005   0.109700311365407
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mySeed=57; % an integer number
rng(mySeed,'twister') %You can replace 'twister' with other generators
```

Comment: Thx. Vote this one up!

Answer (score 0):

When you just want to reset the RNG to some known state, just use:

```
 seed = 0;
 randn('state', seed);
 rand ('state', seed);
 A = round(10*(rand(1,5))); // always will be [10 2 6 5 9]
```