# Seed generator for rand function in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, seed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set custom seed for pseudo-random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682080/how-to-set-custom-seed-for-pseudo-random-number-generator)

I'm trying to set the seed generator for `rand()` function in Matlab but I didn't find the way.Someone could help me?Despite I read the help for that function I didn't understand how set this value.

Comment: Thanks H.Muster.I find that post very useful...I haven't found it before..

Answer (score 3):

The function rng is used to set the seed.

`rng(seed)`