# get same results in every simulation with matlab

Tags: matlab, random, simulation, random-seed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set custom seed for pseudo-random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682080/how-to-set-custom-seed-for-pseudo-random-number-generator)

I'm building some simulations with matlab and I use `rand` function.

I would like to obtain at every run, the same results. I read somewhere I have to set the seed of the rand function. I tried using

```
s = RandStream('mcg16807', 'seed', 0)
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
```

but it didn't work. Did I made a mistake?

```
>> s = RandStream('mcg16807', 'seed', 5)
>> RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
>> rand

ans = 

    0.5645

>> rand
ans = 

    0.3024

>> rand
ans = 

    0.7520
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682080/how-to-set-custom-seed-for-pseudo-random-number-generator)

Comment: @angainor I have already read that post but It didn't work

Comment: What you wrote works perfectly for me. I don't know what else you need. After you call those two lines, rand returns the same numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't worked...I tried...I write this two lines and after call rand() more times but It didn't work...

Comment: I obtain different values every times...

Comment: @angainor posted a screenshot to show you, it didn't worked

Comment: You have to execute again the `RandStream` thing before each `rand`, if you want to have the same result.

Comment: Sure. Every time **after** you seed the generator it starts the generated sequence from the same point. It does not mean it will only generate one number. It will be the same sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `RandStream.setGlobalStream` when you want to start over and get the same set of random numbers:

```
>> s = RandStream('mcg16807', 'seed', 5)
>> RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
>> rand

ans = 

    0.5645

>> rand
ans = 

    0.3024

>> s = RandStream('mcg16807', 'seed', 5)
>> RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
>> rand

ans = 

    0.5645

>> rand
ans = 

    0.3024
```

I typically call `setGlobalStream` only once, at the beginning of the script that I want to give me the same answer every time. The numbers drawn by `rand` are each random, but they are the same set of random numbers every time.

Comment: But if in my scripts I have a for cycle and at every cycle I call rand function, to have the same values I have to call setGlobalStream at every cycle right?

Comment: Technically, that would work. However, it would be much better practice to simply save the result of `rand` in a variable outside the loop and use that variable inside the for loop.