# Random number - Choose seed

Tags: matlab, random, gaussian, normal-distribution

because of one project I have to make use of pseudo random numbers with normal distribution.

To this respect, I'm generally putting this down:

```
nn_u = complex((normrnd(0,1.0,size(H_u))),(normrnd(0,1.0,size(H_u))));
nn_v = complex((normrnd(0,1.0,size(H_u))),(normrnd(0,1.0,size(H_u))));
nn_w = complex((normrnd(0,1.0,size(H_u))),(normrnd(0,1.0,size(H_u))));
size(H_u) = [4096,1];
```

This way I don't have any real access to the seed number. What I expect is that, using the above mentioned form, there will be 6 seeds, that means one different seed for any of the six times called `normrnd` function.

What I'd like to do at the moment is to generate six independent representations, just as happens above, with only one seed point, which I can pick out of the range `[1,999]`.

To achieve this I was thinking to proceed this way:

```
n = 4096;
nn_tmp = normrnd(0,1,[n*6,1]);
nn_u = complex(nn_tmp(1:n,1),nn_tmp(n+1:2*n,1));
nn_v = complex(nn_tmp(2*n+1:3*n,1),nn_tmp(3*n+1:4*n,1));
nn_w = complex(nn_tmp(4*n+1:5*n,1),nn_tmp(5*n+1:6*n,1));
```

But this way, I don't have any direct access to the seed; I don't even know if the kind of operation I'd do has any strong theoretical validation.

Any support would be welcome.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682080/how-to-set-custom-seed-for-pseudo-random-number-generator ?

Comment: A comparison of `RandStream` vs `rng` for interests sake: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/07/07/simpler-control-of-random-number-generation-in-matlab/ but I think both will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [rng](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) to seed and then use `randn` instead of `normrnd` for your problem

So something like

```
SEED = 120; %for example
rng(SEED, 'twister');
nn_u = complex(randn(size(H_u)),randn(size(H_u)));
nn_v = complex(randn(size(H_u)),randn(size(H_u)));
nn_w = complex(randn(size(H_u)),randn(size(H_u)));
```