# Uniform Random Number blocks in my simulation model

Tags: matlab, random, simulink

I've used 2 Uniform Random Number blocks in my simulation model, but every time I run the program they generate last numbers (exactly the same). I need to test the model with new generated numbers. what should I do?

thanks for your helps in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that random number generators generate the same random numbers "from the start" is a feature, not a bug. It allows for reproducible testing. You need to initialize your random number generator with a "random seed" in order to give a different result each time - you could use the current time, for example. When you do, it is recommended that you store the seed used - it means you can go back and run exactly the same code again.

For initializing a random seed, you can use the methods given in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682080/how-to-set-custom-seed-for-pseudo-random-number-generator)

In that answer, they are setting the seed to `0` - this is the opposite of what you are trying to do. You will want to generate a non-random number (like the date), and use that. A very useful article can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/controlling-random-number-generation.html). To quote:

> If you look at the output from rand, randi, or randn in a new MATLAB
>   session, you'll notice that they return the same sequences of numbers
>   each time you restart MATLAB. It's often useful to be able to reset
>   the random number generator to that startup state, without actually
>   restarting MATLAB. For example, you might want to repeat a calculation
>   that involves random numbers, and get the same result.

They recommend the command

```
rng shuffle
```

To generate a new random seed. You can access the seed that was used with

```
rng.seed
```

and store that for future use. So if you co

```
rng shuffle
seedStore = rng.seed;
```

Then next time you want to reproduce results, you set

```
rng(seedStore);
```

Comment: Floris' answer is a good one when strictly using MATLAB.  However the Simulink blocks are a little different.  You need to set/change the seed in the Uniform Random Number generator block's dialog, not at the MATLAB command line, and the block will use that seed every time the model is executed.  To make it "more random" set the set to now().

Comment: @philGoddard - thanks for your update. I was not aware of the difference in Simulink . I will check it out and include the information / links in the answer for completeness.