# cellfun randperm downsampling: keep track of indexes (matlab)

Tags: matlab, indexing, cells

I have this snippet of code, downsampling data from a cell array based on the length of its shortest element.

```
sizeShortest = min(cellfun('size', data, 2));
f=@(x)(x(:,sort(getfield(randperm(size(x,2)),{1:sizeShortest}))));
dummy = cellfun(f, data, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

I would also like to keep track of the indexes of the elements of data saved in dummy (Basically what's the 1:sizeShortest values from the randperm call).

I couldn't find an answer so far...any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just run another `cellfun` command where the anonymous function is simply: `f=@(x) getfield(randperm(size(x,2)),{1:sizeShortest});`?

Comment: I actually thought about it too, but wouldn't this give different values - because of a different randperm call?

Comment: Reset the seed before each call.  That way you're guaranteed to get the same indices.  You can set a random seed before you perform any random function.  That way, the random values that you generate once you set the seed are reproducible.  Use the `rng` command and set it to any number you wish... like 10.  Run your `cellfun` command, then **reset** the seed back to 10.  Run the second `cellfun` command.  More on `rng` here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11148581/3250829 .  I'll write an answer for you.

Comment: Ahhh...ok I didn't think/know about that. That's great, so I can accept your answer! Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome!  I have just added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our comments, you can simply take the code that is indexing your array and obtain your indices:

```
f=@(x) sort(getfield(randperm(size(x,2)),{1:sizeShortest}));
indices = cellfun(f, data, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

In essence, you'd run `cellfun` twice.  Once for getting the data, and again for the indices.  However, as you have cleverly stated in your comments, running `randperm` subsequent times will generate a new sequence of numbers.  You can "cheat" by resetting the random generator seed before you call the next `randperm` call.  What this does is that once you reset the seed, the random numbers that you generate should be reproducible.  You can do this by the `rng` function.  This accepts any integer that will act as a seed.  Once you set this up, the numbers generated by any random generation function will follow a prescribed format that relies on this seed.

As an example:

```
rng(10)
C = randperm(10)
```

This gives:

```
C =

 2    10     9     7     6     5     3     4     8     1
```

If you run those two statements again, you will *get the same sequence stored in `C`*.  As such, set your random number generator to any integer you want.  Run the first `cellfun` command... then after, reset to the *same seed* and run the second `cellfun` command.

Now to make this **truly** dynamic, you'll want to choose a **random seed** first.  Store this number for later so that you can use this same seed for both `cellfun` calls.  You could poll the current time of the day, and use the seconds to give you your custom seed.

In other words:

```
c = clock;
seedNum = c(5);  %// c(5) is the number of seconds in the minute you're currently on.
rng(seedNum);
%// Do your first set of commands here...
rng(seedNum);
%// Do your second set of commands here...
```

If you want to reset it back to default after you're done, you can call `rng('default');`  What this will do is that it will reset the random number generation as if you restarted MATLAB.  You don't have to, but I think it's good practice!

Good luck!